# Initial Value Problem $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x),x(\tau)=\xi$ Equivalent to Integral Equation $x(t)=\xi+\int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, initial-value-problems

I am trying to understand a part of the proof for the following proposition:

> The initial value problem $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x),x(\tau)=\xi$ is equivalent to the integral equation $x(t)=\xi+\int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$.

$(=>)$ Let $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x),x(\tau)=\xi$ be an initial value problem.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x)$

$\int_{\tau}^{t}x'(s)ds = \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$

> How did this $\int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$ become? I am not sure how the $x(s)$ came about. If I integrate the vector field $f(t,x)$ with respect to $s$, where does $x(s)$ come from? I'm not very expert on Multivariable Calculus, sorry!

$x(t)-x(\tau) = \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$

$x(t)-\xi = \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$

$x(t) =\xi+ \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$

$(<=)$ Let $x(t) =\xi+ \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$.

$x(t) =\xi+ \int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds$

$x'(t)=(\xi)'+(\int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds)'$

$x'(t)=0+f(t,x)=f(t,x)$

> Similarly, how come $(\int_{\tau}^{t}f(s,x(s))ds)'=f(t,x)$?

Comment: You know about the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: @LutzL I totally get it now. :) $(\int_{a}^{g(x)}f(t)dt)'=f(g(x))g'(x)$.

Comment: There you have combined the FTC with the chain rule, but where do you find that in the question?